# c# a generic error occurred in gdi+ when save image

Tags: c#, windows

I try this code to resize my image:

```
 ConvertToBitmap(txtImage.Text);

    private void ConvertToBitmap(string filename)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            var origImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename);
            var widthDivisor = (double)origImg.Width / (double)900;
            var heightDivisor = (double)origImg.Height / (double)750;
            int newWidth, newHeight;

            if (widthDivisor < heightDivisor)
            {
                newWidth = (int)((double)origImg.Width / widthDivisor);
                newHeight = (int)((double)origImg.Height / widthDivisor);
            }
            else
            {
                newWidth = (int)((double)origImg.Width / heightDivisor);
                newHeight = (int)((double)origImg.Height / heightDivisor);
            }

            var newImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImg);
            g.DrawImage(origImg, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));
            System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, (long)350);
            newImg.Save(fullpath, GetImageCodeInfo("image/jpeg"), encoderParameters);
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public static ImageCodecInfo GetImageCodeInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo ici in info)
            if (ici.MimeType.Equals(mimeType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return ici;
        return null;
    }

    private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {

        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

it's resize image but some how it shown error `a generic error occurred in gdi+`.
any extra effort are welcome.

Comment: I took your code ran it to see what error it throws and it ran just fine I got an ouput image with modified size...is your error on some other part of your code??

Comment: actually i know that code is work fine in my pc.. but i setup this code in other pc it's through the error

Comment: when image resize it's save in my project folder. @ArifEqbal

Comment: Try to debug it on that machine...On which line does it throw the exception

Comment: I run my desktop application software .exe file it's occur that time that's why i not check by debug the code @ArifEqbal

Comment: This is an error that can occur for many reasons, it can occur when you are saving the image, it can occur when your opening the image it can even occur when resizing, I think there is some limit to the size of image, please search the net for that, your logic to get the newWidth/newHeight might result in some very large size say if the original image is too small vertically and too large horizontally...so in a nutshell one can not guess correctly the source of this error, you might need to do the hardwork of say adding logs etc. to know where the issue is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give security full permission to the folder then it's work very fine

Comment: Can u please share how you set the full permission to the folder in this case? I am facing the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please note the private memory usage when the error occurs. This issue may also occur because of memory leak.

I see the code is handling graphics and other drawing objects which should be properly disposed after use.

Run this method in a loop to see if the memory consumption is drastically increasing. If yes, then there is a memory leak and you have to dig deep to find what object is not getting disposed after use.